# $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z}$ - Circle immersed the point $z=0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like someone explain to me why in the resolution of $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z}$ where $\gamma$ is the square of vertex $-1-i$, $-1+i$, $1-i$ and $1+i$, it is possible to take a unit circle $\gamma_1$ that will immerse the point $z=0$.

[image]

So clearly by the Cauchy theorem, we obtain $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z}=\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i$

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic in the region delimited by the two curves. Hence the contour integral with the two paths is $0$.

Comment: @C.Dubussy Which two curves? Could explain with a bit more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $\gamma$ the square and $\gamma_1$ the unit circle oriented counter-clockwise and $\gamma_1^-$ the circle oriented clockwise. Then $\gamma \cup \gamma_1^-$ delimites a region where $\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic. Hence $$\int_{\gamma \cup \gamma_1^-} \frac{1}{z} dz = 0.$$ But $$\int_{\gamma \cup \gamma_1^-} \frac{1}{z}dz = \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z}dz + \int_{\gamma_1^-} \frac{1}{z}dz = \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z}dz- \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{z}dz.$$