# Contour integral - Circle instead of a square

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I would like to solve the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z \bar{z}} dz$. Here $\gamma \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a square centered at the origin and where his vertices are parallel to the axes. Could I use the Cauchy theorem in using the fact we will change the contour to a unit circle center to the origin?

Comment: Hint: write $1/(z\overline z) = 1/ \lvert z \rvert ^2$ and parametrize.

Comment: I already know that, but I don't the good parametrization?

Comment: Break the integral into four segments; you'll get a a single-variable calculus problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is not holomorphic, you can't use Cauchy integral theorem.

However, if you parametric $\gamma$ by $[0,2\pi] \ni \theta \mapsto z(\theta) = r(\theta) e^{i\theta}$ by a suitable chosen real valued function $r(\theta)$.
The integral becomes

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z\bar{z}} = \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \frac{r'(\theta)+ir(\theta)}{r(\theta)^2} \right) e^{i\theta} d\theta$$

Notice $r(\theta+\pi) = r(\theta)$ while $e^{i(\theta+\pi)} = -e^{i\theta}$. the contribution from $[\pi,2\pi]$ in last integral cancel the one from $[0,\pi]$. So the integral is $0$.

Comment: Little detail : Why do you use a different parametrization instead of the $\gamma$ proposed in the problem (i.e. a square)? Is it because of this result : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694774/int-gamma-fracdzz-circle-immersed-the-point-z-0?noredirect=1#comment3458892_1694774?

Comment: @RobertDavis 1) for suitable choice of $r(\theta)$ (i.e $\min\left(\frac{1}{|\cos\theta|}, \frac{1}{|\sin\theta|}\right)$ ),  you get a square. 2) the integral depends only on the contour/orientation but not the actual parametrization. 3) as long as your contour is centrally symmetric, the integral vanishes. I choose my parametrization to make this easier to describe.

Comment: Since $r(\theta)$ is real, how $r(\theta) e^{i\theta}$ could become a square? I need a bit more explication for you choice of parametrization.

Comment: @RobertDavis for $\theta \in [7\pi/4,2\pi] \cup [0,\pi/4]$, $r(\theta) = \min\left(\frac{1}{|\cos\theta|}, \frac{1}{|\sin\theta|}\right)$ reduces to $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$, so $r(\theta) e^{i\theta}$ becomes $1 + i\tan\theta$ which describe the line segment from $1-i$ to $1+i$. The other three sides of the square can be obtained in similar manner.