# $r(\theta) e^{i\theta}$ - Parametrization of the square $\gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In the question [Contour integral - Circle instead of a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694862/contour-integral-circle-instead-of-a-square) achille hui explains that $r(\theta) e^{i\theta}$ with $r(\theta)\min\left(\frac{1}{|\cos\theta|}, \frac{1}{|\sin\theta|}\right)$ is a suitable choice to get a square. Is anyone could explain to me why this parametrization is correct for how $\gamma$ is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Hint the line $x = 1$ in polar coordinates is $r\cos\theta =1$.